# Create clipboard data for use in Access-Vbe

Tags: c#, vba, ms-access, clipboard

In ms-access its possible to copy&paste controls from the design-view of one form to another form. This is a thing I want to (ab)use.

I want to create a C# programm which simulates this.

The use case is the following:

- Enter some Information in the C#-program
- click a Button in the c# Program => the clipboard-data is createDR
- paste it into a form-design-view in ms-access => The controls are pasted into the form; They got the names, sizes and so on which are determined by the information entered before

As a first test I

So I copied a textfield (Named "BU_NAME", read the clipboard and stored it into a file called: "ClipboardData TextField BU_NAME.txt"

With this code its possible to copy the Input of the file onto the clipboard so afterwards I can paste the Textfield BU_NAME into access.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("ClipboardData TextField BU_NAME.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    file.CopyTo(ms);

Clipboard.SetData("Form Item v12", ms);
```

This seems to work.

As a first test for manipulation I tried to change the name of the textfield with a Hex-Editor. This works as long as I do not change the length of the Name.

So before I start a big project to find out how the clipboard format used by ms-access ("Form Item v12") works:

- Is there any documentation for this format?
- Any tipps which help me to figure out how the format is defined?

Comment: The clipboard formats used by Office are undocumented*. Asking for general help understanding them is way too broad for Stack Overflow. _(* = some formats are somewhat documented, but not the ones used by Access)_

Comment: It would be easier and more straightforward to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.createcontrol

Comment: which formats are documented?

Comment: @Andre: Thats great. I did not know that this is an option. Ill check that out.

Comment: @Gener4tor Loads, see [the Office standards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg548604(v=office.12).aspx). Though for Access, the only real documented format is AXL, which is used by _Application.TransferText_ and macro's. If you want to programatically create forms, I'd look at the [MS-AXL documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd927584(v=office.12).aspx).